# Headless SPA Server Side approach with Content Management Sysstem

Tags: reactjs, aem, single-page-application, next.js, contentful

I am evaluating how is it possible to implement Server Side Rendering in SPA app with React and CMS as backend.

This is the approach I see [Next.js](https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/data-fetching/request-time) suggest to have per-rendered and all most all CMS system suggests:

1. User request a page from react app running on Node server
2. Node server requests JSON data from CMS through fetch call
3. Then React App reads this JSON and transform HTML into String like renderToString() and sends the response back to the user.

The disadvantage of this approach is that if JSON data from CMS is huge then first request takes long time.

What alternate solution do you suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heyooo, Contentful DevRel here.

your concerns are absolutely valid.

And that's why Next.js just recently added [advanced static pre-generation using getStaticProps](https://nextjs.org/blog/next-9-3#next-gen-static-site-generation-ssg-support). The goal is to tackle the long dynamic response times by pre-generating as much as possible. This way the user has a fast initial content paint, but can still enjoy all the dynamic benefits that come with a React application (Next.js usually follows an isomorphic JavaScript architecture)

The processing time you describe then is moved from dynamic request/response time into build-processes.

In general, when you're not dealing with millions of pages, I recommend giving static HTML a try. It makes applications often faster, safer, and more secure. For more complext and larger sites, Vercel is also experimenting with hybrid solutions that offer ways to only pre-generate certain pages. That's all very new though. :)

Comment: we have 50000 pages :) Can you please clarify one concept for me? I want to do react SPA server side but I do not want to use getServerSideProps because it requires multiple pages HTML to be present in the response from server. Is it possible that on navigating different links I make async request to get json and still it will be on Server side?

Comment: > Is it possible that on navigating different links I make async request to get json and still it will be on Server side?

This is exactly the idea of recent frameworks (Next, Gatsby, ...). Serve HTML initially and for further navigations fetch only what you need to render the following pages dynamically. :)

Comment: async call (Next/Gastby) will fetch content from CDN or CMS? in case of CDN, its pre-rendered static HTML which is made available during build time? we cannot keep all of our pages in CDN because they changes content everyday, hence cannot be made available during build time

Comment: Next/Gatsby usually fetch data from the CMS during build time. If you have a lot of changes over the day and rebuilding is not an option because of the build time, then fetching the data on request on the server is the best approach because the server most likely has a better and faster connection than the user. :)

Comment: thanks a lot for taking time to clarify again :) , 1. "then fetching the data on request on the server is the best approach " -> do you mean the 1-2-3 points in my original question? 2. In your another comment "Serve HTML initially and for further navigations fetch only what you need to render the following pages dynamically" ->This fetch is from CMS or CDN? Is it not client side?

Comment: Yes, for a lot of constant data changes the approach you describe it the best IMO because the environment of your servers is controlled and most likely is faster than the client network. For client side navigation that is completely up to you and your framework, usually there a lots of config options. I recommend reading up upon  universal/isomorphic JS frameworks. :)